SharePoint list how to create a view to display two columns with the same resource name
I am seeking for a navigation how to create filter or view in SharePoint list that will enable you to show the same resource name under items where such a resource is displayed in either the "Lead" or "Deputy Lead" columns.
Example - list containing following columns:
Title    Lead      Deputy lead    Assignment
A        John                      
B                   John          
C        John                      
D        Edit       John           

Expected results of the filter based on the name to see is:
John 
   A
   B 
   C
   D

How can I create a filter that will provide me the result. When I filter John, I will see all the assignments he is appearing at?
Thank you very much for your help on this topic.

What is the column type of "Deputy lead" and "Lead"? Are you unable to filter list view based on 2 columns?

both fields are "Person or Group" type....
I am able to filter list based on 2 columns, only I am limited with number of filters, considering i have more then 30 names to filter on, hence i am looking for possibly another solution

You want to add more than 30 filter conditions at a time? If no, you should be able to add filter on 2 columns with single user name at a time from default list view without any issue.

@Ganes Sanap - yes exactly, what i need is to display a resource name(s) showing in  Lead and deputy lead fields to show where they are participating... as described in the initial message. In a lead or deputy lead are number of users, hence with filtering i am limitted to number of filters
